# Where can I find a list of class labels for pretrained SparkNLP NerDLModel?

Tags: tensorflow, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I have been searching for a while but no luck finding out what NER labels are included in the pretrained NerDL(tensorflow) model. I would think the training data can provide such information, but I do not see it mentioned in any documentation.

downloadable model:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/auxdata.johnsnowlabs.com/public/models/ner_precise_en_1.7.0_2_1539623388047.zip

Any direction would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

I indeed filed an issue in SparkNLP github following the advice here :)
I just heard back from them. Here is the answer:

> For practical purposes, the pretrained NER model has
>
> B-ORG
>
> I-ORG
>
> B-PER
>
> I-PER
>
> B-LOC
>
> I-LOC
>
> and it has been trained from:
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patverga/torch-ner-nlp-from-scratch/master/data/conll2003/eng.train

See original issue [here](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/issues/312).

Answer (score 2):

that model is trained on the CONLL2003 dataset for NER,

http://aclweb.org/anthology/W03-0419

That dataset basically has PERSON, ORGANIZATION, and LOCATION.

hope this helps,
Alberto.

Comment: Hi AlbertoAndreotti, is there any documentation mentioned that the `NerDLModel.pretrained()` is trained using the dataset discussed in this paper? I could not find it mentioned anywhere, just wanted to be sure. (I did see the `CoNLL 2003 IOB NER file` under the `Named Entity Recognition Deep Learning annotator`, but that does not really confirm that the pre-trained version is from this dataset)

Comment: That's true they don't mention it. I suggest you to submit an issue to the github project so that detail gets clarified.